# Trying to trigger an Apex class once a check box is marked true on the salesforce front end

Tags: apex, trigger, checkbox

I'm trying to call an Apex Class when a checkbox is marked true either on the SalesForce client front end checkbox or when multiple accounts and contacts are uploaded via CSV & DataLoader when the checkbox is true.

The class and trigger are working and hitting our endpoint to create accounts, but I only want the API call to happen once a custom Contact field "Send_to_Onboarding_Portal__c" is true.

Currently, I'm getting an error: "Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.SObjectField, Boolean"

Any help would be **very much appreciated.**

```
trigger LIFT_ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
   
    if(Contact.Send_to_Onboarding_Portal__c == true) {
        List<Contact> lstContact = Trigger.New;
        Integer numContacts = lstContact.size();
    
        LIFT_ContactBatchCreation cbc = new LIFT_ContactBatchCreation(lstContact);
        id batch = DataBase.executeBatch(cbc,1);
    }
}
```

Apex Class that should get called once checkbox is true

```
/* TODO - Add description of class, author & date */
/* TODO - Add TEST class */
global class LIFT_ContactBatchCreation implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private List<Contact> lstContact;
    public LIFT_ContactBatchCreation(List<Contact> lsacc) {
        System.debug('constructor batch class, ' + lsacc.size());
        this.lstContact = lsacc;
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('start batch class, ' + lstContact.size());
        String soqlQuery = 'SELECT Account.Branch_Id__c, Account.Parent_Account_Name__c, Account.Date_became_Customer__c, Account.Go_Live_Date__c, Account.Name, FirstName, LastName, Email, Id From Contact where Id IN :lstContact';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(soqlQuery);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope){
        System.debug('execute batch class, ' + scope.size());
        for (Contact contact : scope) {
            try {
                System.debug(contact.Account.Name);
                System.debug(contact.Account.Branch_Id__c);
                String accountName = contact.Account.Name;
                String branchId = contact.Account.Branch_Id__c;
                String firstName = contact.FirstName;
                String lastName = contact.LastName;
                String email = contact.Email;
                Date goLiveDate = contact.Account.Go_Live_Date__c;
                Date startDate = contact.Account.Date_became_Customer__c;
                String parentAccountName = contact.Account.Parent_Account_Name__c;
                //TODO - move to separate class for the callout
                Http http = new Http();
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                //TODO - make named credential more generic so can easily be deployed between environments
                request.setEndpoint('callout:Glofox_Portal/api/branches/fromSalesforceDemo');
                request.setMethod('POST');
                request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
                // Set the body as a JSON object
                request.setBody('{"branchId":"'+branchId+'", "parentAccountName":"'+parentAccountName+'", "name":"'+accountName+'", "goLiveDate":"'+goLiveDate+'","startDate":"'+startDate+'" ,"admins":[{"firstName":"'+FirstName+'","lastName":"'+LastName+'","email":"'+email+'"}]}');
                HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
                System.debug(response.getBody());
                // Parse the JSON response
                if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                    //TODO - insert error handling and/or retyr logic here
                    //TODO - log exception in Salesforce including error code and reason
                    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
                } else {
                    //TODO - update status field in Salesforce on success and update externalId
                    System.debug(response.getBody());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error-' + e.getMessage());
                //Log exception
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be in the trigger at below line-

```
if(Contact.Send_to_Onboarding_Portal__c == true)
```

Instead you can build a list like below :-

```
list<contact> lstContact = new list<contact> ();
For(Contact c : trigger.new){
if(c.Send_to_Onboarding_Portal__c){
  lstContact.add(c);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your help @Manish, this is working when the tick box is checked upon contact creation, it fires to our endpoint / and doesnt fire if the checkbox is not checked.

If I don’t initially check the box, when i create the contact and then check the box at a later date it doesn’t send? 

Do you know how I can trigger the API call if the checkbox is checked after contact creation? Many thanks for your help

Comment: You can add 'After Update' event in the trigger.

Comment: Thanks Manish, i noticed that and added it soon after. It's now hitting my endpoint upon updating the checkbox, but in the Apex Batch Jobs / status detail I'm getting the following message even though status is Success.

```First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0035E000013uqk8QAA; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LIFT_ContactTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called ...```

Many thanks